# Run bicep in Complete mode by default?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-bicep

By default, when running something like `az deployment group create --template-file xyz.bicep ...`, bicep is in "Incremental" mode. Because of this, it might happen that things get added while they should've been simply changed.

With `--mode Complete`, this can be changed. But it's of course *"a bit"* annoying to always specify this. It might also mean, that it gets forgotten.

How can I tell the `az` CLI that it should, by default, work in Complete mode instead?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use alis like this one for instance:

```
New-Alias -Name "azd" az deployment group create --mode Complete
```

and then call just:

```
azd --template-file xyz.bicep
```

Comment: But that doesn't take eg. "az deployment group what-if" into consideration, does it? And it's also not present when running az from scripts. Would "azd --mode Interactive" work? Ie., would it allow me to override the Complete mode on a case by case basis?

Comment: You can still pass another parameters like `azd --template-file xyz.bicep what-if`. However it won't allow you to override mode. For this you will be forced to use full syntax. There is no way to change default behavior and this is just workaround. However, not perfect.

Comment: I'm not using Powershell. Only fish shell or sometimes bash. Windows is just there to start WSL ;) And this workaround really isn't that good. Too many loopholes, too many possible issues.

Comment: Yeah, I just notice that. (thus I deleted that comment) It would not work with cli. Sorry, I was trying to be to hurry to help you ;)

Comment: thanks. Let me guess - there's also no way to make "-c" ("--confirm-with-what-if") to be a default?

Comment: You may use this in scripts but you need to be sure to call New-Aliast at the beginning. And you can for isntance create tewo aliases, one for Complete mode, and one for Inceremental.

Comment: Yeah, there is no options to customize defaults. You may relay on aliases, but it makes sense only to some point. Otherwise you will end up with tons of them. (you are good in guessing ;) )